# NullPointerException at createBitmap(). Using an Adapter to inflate a Bitmap into a ListView's rows

Tags: java, android, xml, bitmap

I'm getting a NullPointerException at createBitmap. On research, I've come across people suggesting it's because of low memory. I'd like to find out if there's anything in my code that could be changed to make it work. For reference, I'll also post the XML file of the row to give an idea of how it should fit in.

Here's the function that gives the error (I'm trying to make the image circular, with this function):

```
public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, View view) {
    Bitmap output;
    try {
        view.buildDrawingCache(true);
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), //Error here
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }finally {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    }

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    int halfWidth = bitmap.getWidth()/2;
    int halfHeight = bitmap.getHeight()/2;

    canvas.drawCircle(halfWidth, halfHeight, Math.max(halfWidth, halfHeight), paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Here's the XML code for the row:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:stateListAnimator="@anim/anim"
                                cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@color/material_black_900"
                                cardview:cardElevation="5dp"
                                cardview:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_view"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Test1"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name_view"
        android:text="Test2"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the logCat:

```
    12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2040)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1870)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1652)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1510)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:443)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1594)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1652)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1510)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:443)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1652)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1510)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:443)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1652)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1510)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:443)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11418)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4328)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 07:51:51.199: E/AndroidRuntime(21433):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
```

Comment: Where is this called from? Is it possible that the `Bitmap` parameter is null when this function is called?

Comment: and please provide the logcat

Comment: @BlazeTama I've added the LogCat.

Comment: @McAdam331, not that isn't the case. I've tried without this function, and it works fine.

Comment: I'm only guessing but it's possible your research is right. Notice how none of *your* files are in that stacktrace? That makes me think there's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @McAdam331 is there a workaround?

Comment: low memory would throw an OutOfMemoryException, not a NullPointerException. It's difficult to tell what's happening as you post two apparently unrelated chunks of code, the logcat shows the app is crashing on laying out a row that's being created inside a listview inside a viewpager. Check your adapter getView().

Comment: @user2474562 sorry for long response. Please post where you use `getCroppedBitmap`

Comment: @BlazeTama, I'm sorry, I've ditched this code and done something different. I'm going to let the question stay anyways, if someone would like to answer with the little information there is in my description. Could prove useful to someone.